# Am I Understanding Orbits Correctly?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm studying some abstract algebra and would just like some clarification/verification that I'm understanding orbits right. From what I understand, an orbit is "everything that can be reached from $x$ by an action of something in $G$." Then, for this problem:

Let $x$ be the midpoint of the left side of the square, and let $D_4$ (symmetries of a square) act on the square. What is the orbit of $x$ under $D_4$? Under $<R_{90}>$?

From the above intuitive definition of an orbit, the orbits of $x$ under $D_4$ would be all the possible positions of $x$ from the symmetries of the square, right? So, the orbits would be all 4 midpoints of the square, since all of them are "reachable" from the actions of $D_4$? Similarly, for $<R_{90}>$, it would be all the positions reachable by $x$ from rotation clockwise by 90 degrees? (which would be the same as $D_4$).

Am I misunderstanding what orbits are, or am I on the right track? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. The orbit of $x$ under $G$, often denoted $G.x$, is the set $\{gx| g\in G\}$ i.e. it is the set of all places where $x$ goes as we hit with different $g$. What's interesting in this case is that $x$ has the same orbit under both the full group and the subgroup of rotations, but this happens in cases where different group elements act equivalently on $x$.